# New to Sharepoint. Best practices in wiki creation?

Tags: wiki

I am brand new to SP. I have been charged with creating a site for our group. I have posted a couple of questions previously, which you folks have been very helpful with.

I have been asked to make a wiki which will allow our group to post info regarding their 'knowledge area' ie. java, .NET, different DBs we use, etc. Originally, I had all pages for every area all in one centralized library, and then created views for each area via a custom column. I then set up some rudimentary navigation so the user didn't automatically get a view of all pages (which would be confusing).

My question is this:

Is it best to do it this way, or should I create a different wiki library for each of our ten or twelve 'knowledge areas', and then link to the different libraries?

Does it even make a difference? We are not a huge group, around 20-30 users. I thought about it last night, and could not think of any reason to take one over the other.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For consistancy, I'd just use one wiki library since your a small group of users.  Add a choice column to the wiki with all of your Knowledge Areas and when wiki pages are created, they can be classified.  Then you can create multiple views to let users sort through the data by Knowledge Area.

Comment: Cool. That is how I had it before. So I guess I just need to leave well enough alone.